# Is it possible to have a dart project and a java project within a same repository

Tags: git, google-app-engine, dart

I have a project where server side developed as an appengine project and client side developed as dart project.Can I have both projects in a same git repository?

Comment: I have several repositories. so I wanted this in a single place since it is actually a single project implemented with two different technologies. If it is possible, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes: A file is a file

Git only cares about files - it' does not care at all what *kind* of files you put in it.

As such: yes, you can put a dart project and a java project in the same repository.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have a server-side Java app and a client-side Dart app in the same repository.

It's all about how you want to structure your source code.

There's nothing stopping you from doing this.